# Postgresql function table name parameter

Tags: postgresql, function, parameters

I have *n* tables sharing a least one column name ("Date"), I want to create a function which can make a

`select column1, column2, ..., columnx from myfunction('table_name','date_value')`

First, tried with just table name parameter (excerpt from another post on this website) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(_tbl regclass, OUT result integer) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT (EXISTS (SELECT FROM %s))::int', _tbl)
   INTO result;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and called with  `SELECT test('"vDxi"');` but the result is :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 1: SELECT (EXISTS (SELECT FROM "vDxi"))::int
                               ^
QUERY:  SELECT (EXISTS (SELECT FROM "vDxi"))::int
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test(regclass) line 3 at EXECUTE statement
SQL state: 42601
```

Since I'm a real newbie in PLSQL, I don't know where the error is (tried a `SELECT * ...` with no success).

And the calling query does not permit me to select column names, if I can make it working...

Comment: have you tried removing the `"`? Something like `SELECT test('vDxi');`

Comment: With only double quote, I've "column does not exist", with only single quote, I've "relation does not exist".

Comment: If the tables all have the same columns, you could write such a function. Otherwise it cannot be done in a reasonable way. Why do you want to do this on the server and not in client code?

Comment: Tables have not whole common columns. I want to do this on the server because the database will be accessed by different ways : perl batch programs, web server, even excel spreadsheets... so I don't want to re-write queries 3 (or more) times...

Comment: Could it be that you're forgetting the `*` in the query? `SELECT FROM "vDxi"` @Denis.A

Comment: does the relation vDxi actually exist? If you are checking for existence of something you can look in information_schema table. You cannot do `select from non_existent_entity` without getting an error

Comment: with a `*` in the function definition, I got a result of one row containing one column named test with the value of '1'

Comment: @Julia Leder : vDxi is a table view (of table name Dxi). Of course, it exists...